# Solid State Relay Heat Release

Tags: solid-state-relay, enclosure, heat-protection

I want to use a SSR (AD-SSR6T25-DC-280A) to switch on and off a 24 VAC water solenoid valve. The solenoid has an in-rush current of .9A, with a 400mA holding current. I want to mount the SSR in an enclosed panel without a heat sink or ventilation. My question is this...will the SSR release enough heat to cause extreme temperatures in the panel. I want the inside of the panel to remain at around 70 degrees Fahrenheit.

Comment: https://cdn.automationdirect.com/static/specs/ssclass6relays.pdf

Comment: That seems fairly ambitious, what's the temperature outside the panel?

Comment: The temperature outside of the panel is around 70 degrees Fahrenheit, year round.

Comment: With no temperature difference between panel and ambient, you'll have to re-think something. Perhaps the definition of "around" 70F, allowing up to say 100F, giving you some kind of thermal gradient.

Answer (score 1):

[AD-SSR6T25-DC-280A](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/relays_-z-_timers/solid_state_relays/panel_mount_relays,_hockey_puck_style,10a_-_75a_(ad-ssr6_series)/ad-ssr6t25-dc-280a) is a triac based SSR, as such you can expect a 2V drop, so at 400mA expect it to make about 800mW of heat plus whatever power it takes in the input.

At about 1W it should be fine inside a metal enclosure. (that's about 3.4btu/hr in American units)

The brief inrush current will be happening to a cold relay, and as such it can be ignored.

Comment: The enclosure I'm using is plastic, should that still work?

Comment: I would expect it to be fine, 1W is not a lot of heating. the enclosure will be warm to the touch, but not hot enough to melt.